# Why can't I edit this image in Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, carrierwave

I have two Mongoid models, Store and Product. Their relationship is that a Store has_many Products, and Products belongs_to Store. Each of these models has some images that can be attached using Carrierwave, that look like this:

```
mount_uploader :logo, ImageUploader
```

I am able to add and edit images that are in the Store model. But in Product I can only add an image on creation off a Product, but not with editing a product.  This seems somehow to be a deep_copy issue, similar to how in Mongoid if you have an array called urls and you want to update that array, you must call

```
urls_will_change!
```

So I have tried calling the equivalent method (logo_will_change!) inside of a before_update callback, but it doesn't do anything.  Is there somewhere else I should be doing this or is it another problem?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try and upload an image on error, or the new image just doesn't show? Can you post your `update` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked for me, so there may be something else going on:

```
# store model
class Store
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :products
  field :name, type: String
end

# product model
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :store
  field :name, type: String  
end

# image uploader
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end

# some test data
@store = Store.new({:name => "store"})
@product = Product.new({:name => "product"})
@store.save
@store.products << @product

# later get the product and update the image
@product = Product.first
puts @product.image.url # blank
@product.update_attributes({:image => File.open("/path/to/image.png")})
puts @product.image.url # now has image url
```